# Syntax Error when trying to run rails runner on test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a script to be run with rails runner. I tested it locally and it worked just fine, but on a remote server (it's deployed to AWS) it throws the following error:

```
/home/ubuntu/my-project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.1
/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:62: 
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
```

Full error message here:

```
/home/ubuntu/my-project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.1/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:62:in `eval': /home/ubuntu/my-project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.1/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:62: unknown regexp options - rt (SyntaxError)
/home/ubuntu/my-project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.1/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:62: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
/script/content_update.rb
                               ^
    from /home/ubuntu/my-project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.1/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/ubuntu/my-project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `require'
    from /home/ubuntu/my-project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:128:in `require_command!'
    from /home/ubuntu/my-project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:95:in `runner'
    from /home/ubuntu/my-project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/ubuntu/my-project/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.14.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any idea which the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute the command like this:

```
rails runner script/content_update.rb
```

Where `script/content_update.rb` is the correct path to your script.

When you specify it like `/script/content_update.rb` `Rails` searches it in a wrong location and can't find it. When the file is not found, `Rails` treats the string as a `Ruby` script and tries to execute it, and then raises this strange exception.

Comment: This lead me in the right direction, I was attempting to run `rails runner` a directory up from root. It throws a completely meaningless and dark alley error of `undefined local variable or method <script name here> for main:Object (NameError)`...